# JQuery parse feed getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, feed, getelementsbytagname

I am parsing this feed: http://www.kingola.com/feed/podcast/

```
var feedParser = $('<div/>');
var url = 'http://www.kingola.com/feed/podcast/';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false
}).done(function( result ) {

    feedParser.html(d.contents);
    var arr = feedParser[0].getElementsByTagName('item'), i, len = arr.length, entry, obj;

    for(i=0; i < len; i++){
        entry = arr[i];
        obj = {};

        if(typeof entry.getElementsByTagName('title')[0] !== 'undefined'){
            obj.title = entry.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
        if(typeof entry.getElementsByTagName('link')[0] !== 'undefined'){
            obj.link= entry.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }

        finishData.push(obj);

    }

}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

});
```

The problem is that it gets the title but for the link I get undefined on this:

```
entry.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

The command is the same as for the title.

What is this happening and how to solve it?

```
entry.getElementsByTagName('link')[0]    returns <link>
entry.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].childNodes     returns {}
entry.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].childNodes[0]     retruns undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery to get the element values
e.g.

var lName = $('#linkName').text();

Comment: I dont understand. 1. How do I apply this code to example above? 2. There is no 'linkName' node in the feed above as I can see.